# Guardar el resultado de una función

Tags: r

Tengo dos df:

```
df1<-data.frame(col1=c("pruebaA","pruebaA","pruebaA","pruebaB","pruebaB","pruebaB"),col2=c("avion","casa","coche","verde","antonio","jardin"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df2<-data.frame(col1=c("pruebaA","pruebaA","pruebaA","pruebaB","pruebaB","pruebaA"),col2=c("avion","casa grande","coche rojo","Berde","antoñito","jardinn"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

y le quiero aplicar fastLink

```
library(fastLink)


  modelo<- fastLink(
    dfA = df1, dfB = df2,
    varnames = c("col1","col2"),
    partial.match = c("col2"),
    stringdist.match = c("col2"))
```

Guardo el resultado que me interesa.

```
(indices<-modelo$matches)
```

Ahora quiero hacer lo mismo con varios df, por lo que crearé blucles, pero
antes realizo una prueba con un solo dato para ver como guardar la información

```
indices<- list()
prueba <- function(d1, d2) {
  fastLink(
    dfA = d1, dfB = d2,
    varnames = c("col1","col2"),
    partial.match = c("col2"),
    stringdist.match = c("col2")
  )
  indices[1]<-prueba$matches
}


prueba(df1,df2)
```

y no consigo guardar el resultado. He probado con return y tampoco doy con la tecla.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas asignar el resultado de `fastLink` dentro de la función y luego llamarlo en la salida:

```
prueba <- function(d1, d2) {
  out <- fastLink(
    dfA = d1, dfB = d2,
    varnames = c("col1","col2"),
    partial.match = c("col2"),
    stringdist.match = c("col2")
  )
  out$matches
}
```

Con respecto a la salida a lista dentro de esta misma función. Creo que es buena práctica que la función `prueba` solo produzca un output simple y sea otra función la encargada del iterar y ordenar los outputs. Eso podría ser con un bucle o, mejor aún, con alguna funcional. Va un ejemplo con `map2`.

Creo dos listas con data.frame. Los pares a matchear con fastLink están en ambas listas, es decir, va a matchear el elemento 1 de la la lista `.x` con el elemento 1 de la lista `.y`.

```
list(df1, df2) -> foo
list(df2, df1) -> bar
```

Ahora uso la función `map2` pasando ambas listas como argumentos.

```
map2(foo, bar, ~prueba(.x, .y))
```

Después de una impresión en pantalla que hace `fastLink` y que no logro anular obtengo:

```
[[1]]
  inds.a inds.b
1      1      1
2      3      3
3      5      5
4      6      6

[[2]]
  inds.a inds.b
1      1      1
2      3      3
3      5      5
4      6      6
```

Sin problemas le podrías asignar un nombre al output del `map2`, que va a ser una lista de data.frame los matches de cada par.

Comment: pero map2(foo, bar, ~prueba(.x, .y)) hace dos veces lo mismo, no? comparar df1 y df2 dos veces. Tengo varios df que comparar, en plan df1 vs df2 , df1 vs df3, df2 vs df3 y doblar el tiempo no es buena idea. Voy a poner otra pregunta para que se entienda bien lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Sí, es que es solo una prueba de concepto. En tu caso deberías armar las dos listas emparejdas `foo` y `bar`  poniendo, en la misma posición de la lista, los data.frame que te interesa pasar como `dfA` y `dfB` a fastLink

Comment: Pero entiendo que map2 recibe siempre dos df. Creo que no me serviría cuando la cantidad de df a analizar en grande. Aqui he dejado una pregunta aclarando mejor mi problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/421669/fastlink-en-bucle

Comment: Creo entender que podría hacer                                                                                list(df1A, df1B,df1C,df1D,....) -> foo                                                                    list(df2A, df2B,df2C,df2D....) -> bar                                                                            Para comparar los distintos df.

Comment: Sí, creo que esa sería la solución.